# Consume WCF REST basic auth service in Xamarin using System.ServiceModel

Tags: c#, android, wcf, rest, xamarin

I have a RESTful service over HTTPS with basic authentication enabled. I can consume it using below code in "normal" Windows Console application:

```
        var uri = "https://example.com/service";
        var binding = new WebHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity();
        binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, uri);
        factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
        factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";
        factory.Open();
        IService service = factory.CreateChannel();
        service.SomeMethod();
```

But when I use exactly the same code in the Xamarin Android app I receive WebException:

> There was an error on processing web request: Status code 401(Unauthorized): Unauthorized

I'm new to the Xamarin, but as far as I know the ServiceModel implementation is the same as in the Silverlight.

Please help mi solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it cannot be done using this API. That is why `binding.Security.Transport` is *null* after creating `WebHttpBinding` in Xamarin/Android app (it is not *null* in "normal" console application).

The solution is to use low level `HttpWebRequest`:

```
    public void GetDataFromRestService()
    {
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://example.com/service/SomeMethod");
        SetBasicAuthHeader(request, "user", "password");

        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("ERROR: Server status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
            }
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("ERROR: Empty response.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", content);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest request, String userName, String userPassword)
    {
        string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
    }
```

After that we need to manually parse returned JSON content (there is Json.NET for Xamarin). Or we can use some library like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) that is also avaiable for Xamarin and makes things easier.